# How to create application type "Other" in OAuth Client ID in Google

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-apps-script-api

I want to execute Google Apps Script from external Node.js App.

And I tried the following manual, Step3. 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#step_3_configure_the_calling_application

According to 1-c "Choose Other when selecting the Application type", but there is not "other" selection in my select tab.
like this image -> [image: no "other"]

Pleease let me know about how to choose "other" application type.

Comment: thanks for your answer, roma. but here is a statement means service account could not working!   "The Apps Script API doesn't work with service accounts" :https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute

Comment: Do >+ Create credentials> Help me choose

Comment: My bad. Never tried that. Thanks for notice.

Comment: thanks, TheMaster. I tried and choose "Apps Script API" and "Other non UI (e.g. cron-job, daemon)". And then, it says "User data cannot be accessed from a platform without a UI because it requires user interaction for sign-in."  So, can't i use "other" type OAuth for my node.js app without GUI?

Comment: @Sesame No. Node should open the browser for first sign-in. Choose "other Ui(CLI- command line tool)" or "webserver(node.js)"

Comment: @TheMaster I got it! thank you so much.

Answer (score 16):

It's called a "Desktop App" now.

Comment: Thanks! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: How to get the code now?